# .htaccess is not eliminating .html at the end of URLs because the file has the same name as the directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

I am able to get rid of the .html at the end of my website URLs through the .htaccess file but when there is a directory with the same name as the html file the code does not work. Can anyone please provide a set of coding that will fix my problem.

Here is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Please share your .htaccess code I ll fix it for you

Comment: Please edit question and include your current rules. In order to see what's going on we need to see your code.  [That's how this site works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise you can start with multiviews.